# Capture Node JS route's response using AJAX and display it on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ajax

Currently I am taking inputs from client side HTML/JS (var1 and var2) which is being sent back to sever-side Node JS. An AJAX post call is made and the route stores the input values in variables.

Now I want the values of var1 and var2 to be defined at server side Node JS and capture the response using AJAX.

*index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myButton").click(function(){
                var str1 = $("#ip1").val();
                var str2 = $("#ip2").val();

            $.ajax({
                     url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route1",
                     type: 'POST',
                     dataType:'json',
                     data: {var1: str1, var2: str2 },
                     success: function(res) {
                        divData='';
                        $.each(res.result1, function(i, key) {                       
                            divData=' <tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+res.result2[i]+'</td></tr>';
                            $('#restab').append(divData);                            
                        });                                                 
                        }
                    });    
                });                   
         });
</script>
```

*app.js*

```
router.post('/route1', function(req, res1){ 
    var1 = req.body.var1;
    var2 = req.body.var2; 
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
});
```

Instead of sending the data to Node JS and I wish to declare the values on sever side Node JS and the response sent by the route needs to be displayed on HTML as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a response on your api route:

```
var var1, var2;
router.post('/route1', function(req, res1){ 
    var1 = "value of var1";
    var2 = "value of var2"; 
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
    // Send response here:
    res.json({var1, var2})
});
```

You can access it on your ajax success propery:

```
// ...
success: function(res) {
    console.log(res.data.var1);
    console.log(res.data.var2);
}
```

Comment: Instead taking inputs from my HTML var1 = req.body.var1;
I wish to define the value of var1 in app.js i.e. var1="value of var1" and route then sends a response (I haven't included the entire code). Can I assign the value of var1 like you've shown?